# Android: GPS - several satellites in view but none used in fix

Tags: android, gps

Is there any reason why sometimes there are several satellites in view but none of them are used in fix?

I've made a small app to track gps locations, and sometimes it shows 8+ satellites in view, but none are used in fix.

Take a look at the picture below. It illustrates what is happening:

[image]

Every "green arrow" points to a location+direction the device was. Red lines are the "gaps" that I'm talking about. The phone was on, the app was running and locationmanager was receiving "satellites status updates" all the time, but in red lines it gets 0 satellites "used in fix".

This is happening with several different device models (phone and tablets) and with different android versions (3.x to 4.x).

I'm trying to figure this out. Appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

Some relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // when service is created, we start monitoring gps status 

    GpsStatus.Listener gpsStatusListener        = new GpsStatus.Listener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
        {
                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) GooglePlayLocationServices.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                GpsStatus gpsStatus = lm.getGpsStatus(null);
                String msg = "";

                if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED)
                {
                        msg = "onGpsStatusChanged: " + "GPS_EVENT_STARTED";
                }
                else if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED)
                {
                        msg = "onGpsStatusChanged: " + "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED";
                }
                else if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX)
                {
                        msg = "onGpsStatusChanged: " + "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX";
                        msg += " = " + ((gpsStatus != null) ? gpsStatus.getTimeToFirstFix() / 1000 : 0) + "s";
                }
                else if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS)
                {
                        msg = "onGpsStatusChanged: " + "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS";
                        if (gpsStatus != null)
                        {
                                Iterable<GpsSatellite> satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
                                Iterator<GpsSatellite> sat = satellites.iterator();
                                int i = 0;
                                int used = 0;
                                while (sat.hasNext())
                                {
                                        i++;
                                        GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
                                        if (satellite.usedInFix())
                                                used++;
                                }
                                msg += " - satelites = " + used + "/" + i;
                                lastSatelitesInfo = used + "/" + i;
                        }
                }
                if (msg.length() > 0)
                        log(msg);
        }

    };

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);
)
```

Log output:

```
[02/09/14 18:42:01] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 18:42:02] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 18:42:03] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
...
[02/09/14 18:44:23] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 18:44:24] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 18:44:25] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
...
[02/09/14 18:52:08] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 18:52:09] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 18:52:10] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
...
[02/09/14 19:56:32] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 19:56:33] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
[02/09/14 19:56:34] onGpsStatusChanged: GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS - satelites = 0/11
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The device may be asleep during these "gaps" - When you turn off your screen the device goes to sleep, and applications no longer receive access to the CPU and can't do anything.

If you want to make sure the device is awake during the tracking period, you need to acquire a `PowerManager.WakeLock`. Assuming this is your method:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock;

public void doSomething() {
    mWakelock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE))
                .newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "wakelock_name");

    mWakelock.acquire();

    // Your long-running code

    mWakelock.release();
}
```

Also, if you do that, don't forget to add the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. 1) I already acquire a wake-lock while tracking. As I mentioned, I still getting satellites updates (8 sats in view, but none in fix, and so on...). So the app is awake all the time! 2) Also as I mentioned, I did this test with dozens of devices.

Comment: Can you attach relevant source code? This was the only thing that came to mind without actually seeing your code...